# How do I view the Ruby method #lcm in the source code?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand how `#lcm` works. It belongs in the `Integer` class, as seen on the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-lcm). I've looked at [Ruby's github page](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) but I don't know how to navigate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I very much prefer to read [Rubinius's source code](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/integer.rb#L131-138) over reading YARV's. Rubinius is much better structured, much better factored, and, above all, most of it is written in a language Ruby programmers know very well, namely Ruby:

```
def lcm(other)
  raise TypeError, "Expected Integer but got #{other.class}" unless other.kind_of?(Integer)
  if self.zero? or other.zero?
    0
  else
    (self.div(self.gcd(other)) * other).abs
  end
end
```

[IronRuby's source code](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/Ruby/Libraries/Builtins/Integer.cs#L518-531) is also well structured, but unfortunately no longer really maintained:

```csharp
[RubyMethod("lcm")]
public static object/*!*/ Lcm(int self, int other) {
    return Lcm(self, other, SignedGcd(self, other));
}

[RubyMethod("lcm")]
public static object/*!*/ Lcm(BigInteger/*!*/ self, BigInteger/*!*/ other) {
    return Lcm(self, other, SignedGcd(self, other));
}

[RubyMethod("lcm")]
public static object/*!*/ Lcm(object/*!*/ self, object other) {
    throw RubyExceptions.CreateTypeError("not an integer");
}
```

My third choice would be [JRuby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyInteger.java#L494-501):

```java
public IRubyObject lcm(ThreadContext context, IRubyObject other) {
    checkInteger(context, other);
    return f_lcm(context, this, RubyRational.intValue(context, other));
}
```

Which points to [this](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/util/Numeric.java#L427-435):

```java
public static IRubyObject f_lcm(ThreadContext context, IRubyObject x, IRubyObject y) {
    if (f_zero_p(context, x) || f_zero_p(context, y)) {
        return RubyFixnum.zero(context.runtime);
    }
    return f_abs(context, f_mul(context, f_div(context, x, f_gcd(context, x, y)), y));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you hover over a method in the Ruby docs you'll see "click to toggle source" on the right. Click on it and you'll see its definition:

```c
VALUE
rb_lcm(VALUE self, VALUE other)
{
    other = nurat_int_value(other);
    return f_lcm(self, other);
}
```

This is C code, of course, rather than Ruby. Many of Ruby's core modules are implemented in C. For such modules I recommend another source of information: The [Ruby Cross-Reference](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source). There you can search for any C identifier, such as `rb_lcm`, and find its definition. In the case of `Integer#lcm` it's actually [defined in `rational.c`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/rational.c#1717) (which you'll find in the root directory on GitHub). From there you can click on `f_lcm` to see [its definition](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/rational.c#352):

```
static VALUE
f_lcm(VALUE x, VALUE y)
{
    if (f_zero_p(x) || f_zero_p(y))
        return ZERO;
    return f_abs(f_mul(f_div(x, f_gcd(x, y)), y));
}
```

...and so on.